# Casting NSString to unsigned char *

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to use a function that has the following signature to sign a HTTP request:

```
extern void hmac_sha1(const unsigned char *inText, int inTextLength, unsigned char* inKey, const unsigned int inKeyLength, unsigned char *outDigest);
```

And this is the method I wrote to use it:

```
- (NSString *)sign: (NSString *)stringToSign {
    NSString *secretKey = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    const unsigned char *inText = (unsigned char *)[stringToSign UTF8String];
    int inTextLength = [stringToSign length];
    unsigned char *inKey = (unsigned char *)[secretKey UTF8String];
    const unsigned int inKeyLength = (unsigned int)[secretKey length];
    unsigned char *outDigest;

    hmac_sha1(inText, inTextLength, inKey, inKeyLength, outDigest);
    NSString *output = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)outDigest];

    return output;
}
```

The problem is I'm sure this is not the way I'm supposed to do this casting, as inside this `hmac_sha1` function I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception.

Since I am new to Objective-C and have close to no experience in C (surprise!) I don't really know what to search for. Any tips on how I can start solving this?

Thanks in advance!

BTW, I got the reference for this function [here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476455/is-there-a-library-for-iphone-to-work-with-hmac-sha-1-encoding/476513).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem is not with the casting, but with `outDigest`. The fifth argument to `hmac_sha1` should point to an already allocated buffer of size 20 bytes (I think).

If you change the line that says

```
unsigned char *outDigest;
```

to say

```
#define HMACSHA1_DIGEST_SIZE 20
void *outDigest = malloc(HMACSHA1_DIGEST_SIZE);
```

That should get you past the crash inside `hmac_sha1`.

Then you've got the problem of converting the data at `outDigest` into an `NSString`. It looks like `hmac_sha1` will put 20 bytes of random-looking data at `outDigest`, and not a null terminated UTF-8 string, so `stringWithUTF8String:` won't work. You might want to use something like this instead if you have to return an `NSString`:

```
NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:outDigest
                                     length:HMACSHA1_DIGEST_SIZE
                                     encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                     freeWhenDone:YES];
```

I don't think `NSString` is really the right type for the digest, so it might be worth changing your method to return an `NSData` if you can.

Comment: That solved it. I'm still going to Base64 encode it, so I can use as a HTTP GET parameter, so I have to keep it in a NSString. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This wasn't part of your question but it's a bug nonetheless, you shouldn't use `-length` to get the byte count of an UTF8 string. That method returns the number of Unicode characters in the string, not the number of bytes. What you want is `-lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:`.

```
NSUInteger byteCount = [stringToSign lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Also be aware that the result does not account for a terminating NULL character.

Comment: Not sure why this got voted down but it's a legitimate issue with the code above. Especially if stringToSign contains any multi-byte UTF8 characters. In that situation the value returned by length will not match the number of bytes returned by UTF8String.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't need to allocate some memory for `outDigest` before calling `hmac_sha1`? Since you pass in a pointer, rather than a pointer to a pointer, there's no way that the memory can be allocated inside the routine.

Comment: I believe you're right.  Looking through the code in http://www.koders.com/c/fid716FD533B2D3ED4F230292A6F9617821C8FDD3D4.aspx it appears that it expects outDigest to be 20 bytes long.

Comment: How do I do this? I tried unsigned char *outDigest = (unsigned char *)malloc(64*sizeof(char)); and unsigned char outDigest[20]; but I couldn't get to cast the result to an actual NSString. (but at least the exception is gone!)

Comment: Without knowing exactly what hmac_sha1 returns it's difficult to be sure, but Will Harris might be on to something.

Comment: Yep. That was it. Now I'm on to base64 encode it. :) Thank you!