# Uploading to Amazon S3 Services from iPhone App

Tags: iphone, rest, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am pulling my hair out on this one... I am using the ASIHTTPRequest (http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) wrapper library for accessing Amazon S3 storage. I am able to connect just fine and grab a listing of buckets without any problems. My frustration is with trying to UPLOAD (PUT and/or POST) a new object (a photo) to an existing bucket. I am following Amazon's documentation to the letter, (at least I think I am.) but nothing seems to work.

Please, someone help me before I jump out of a window. I don't want to die. :-(

Thanks in advance for ANY help I can get.

L.

Comment: Hmmmm - pretty hard to help without any details beyond 'it doesn't work'. What specifically? Fails in what way? Code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a basic example using PUT. Obviously you should be using a queue rather than a synchronous request in the real world.

If you change the amz headers, don't forget to update 'canonicalizedAmzHeaders' as per Amazon's instructions.

```
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>

...

- (void)testS3
{
   NSString *filePath = @"/path/to/file";
   NSString *contentType = @"text/plain";
   NSString *bucket = @"mybucket";
   NSString *path = @"test";
   NSString *secretAccessKey = @"my-secret-access-key";
   NSString *accessKey = @"my-access-key";

   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz"];
   NSString *date = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@.s3.amazonaws.com/%@",bucket,path]]] autorelease];
   [request setPostBodyFilePath:filePath];
   [request setShouldStreamPostDataFromDisk:YES];
   [request setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];

   [request addRequestHeader:@"x-amz-acl" value:@"private"];
   [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:contentType];
   [request addRequestHeader:@"Date" value:date];

   NSString *canonicalizedAmzHeaders = @"x-amz-acl:private";
   NSString *canonicalizedResource = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/%@",bucket,path];
   NSString *stringToSign = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PUT\n\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@",contentType,date,canonicalizedAmzHeaders,canonicalizedResource];

   NSString *signature = [self base64forData:[self HMACSHA1withKey:secretAccessKey forString:stringToSign]];
   NSString *auth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"AWS %@:%@",accessKey,signature];
   [request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:auth];


   [request start];
   NSLog(@"%@",[request responseString]);

}


// Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476455/is-there-a-library-for-iphone-to-work-with-hmac-sha-1-encoding

- (NSData *)HMACSHA1withKey:(NSString *)key forString:(NSString *)string
{
   NSData *clearTextData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};

   CCHmacContext hmacContext;
   CCHmacInit(&hmacContext, kCCHmacAlgSHA1, keyData.bytes, keyData.length);
   CCHmacUpdate(&hmacContext, clearTextData.bytes, clearTextData.length);
   CCHmacFinal(&hmacContext, digest);

   return [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
}

//Source http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour

- (NSString *)base64forData:(NSData *)data
{
    static const char encodingTable[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    if ([data length] == 0)
        return @"";

    char *characters = malloc((([data length] + 2) / 3) * 4);
    if (characters == NULL)
        return nil;
    NSUInteger length = 0;

    NSUInteger i = 0;
    while (i < [data length])
    {
        char buffer[3] = {0,0,0};
        short bufferLength = 0;
        while (bufferLength < 3 && i < [data length])
            buffer[bufferLength++] = ((char *)[data bytes])[i++];

        //  Encode the bytes in the buffer to four characters, including padding "=" characters if necessary.
        characters[length++] = encodingTable[(buffer[0] & 0xFC) >> 2];
        characters[length++] = encodingTable[((buffer[0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((buffer[1] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
        if (bufferLength > 1)
            characters[length++] = encodingTable[((buffer[1] & 0x0F) << 2) | ((buffer[2] & 0xC0) >> 6)];
        else characters[length++] = '=';
        if (bufferLength > 2)
            characters[length++] = encodingTable[buffer[2] & 0x3F];
        else characters[length++] = '=';    
    }

    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:characters length:length encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding freeWhenDone:YES] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: You Rock pokeb. Really appreciate the help. My canonicalizedAmzHeader was all screwy. I'm having one other problem however... I tried to "add" the request to a queue and start it from there but to no avail. Here is my code:
[networkQueue cancelAllOperations];
[request..... definitions go here];
[networkQueue addOperation:request];
[networkQueue go];

What things should I be on the look out for when adding a request to a queue?

thanks again for the help!

L.

Comment: Did you create the queue first?
(eg: [self setNetworkQueue:[ASINetworkQueue queue]])

Comment: You were right again. My networkQueue instance variable was never getting initialized. You ARE the man. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 11):

In case it's helpful for anyone finding this question - Basic S3 support is now built in to ASIHTTPRequest:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/S3

I'd been thinking about adding S3 support for ages, but your question nudged it to the front of the queue :)

Comment: NICE! I love the wrapper. I've become your biggest fan. Keep up the GREAT work!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is an iOS SDK from Amazon now, currently (April 2011) in beta: http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [Connection Kit](http://opensource.utr-software.com/connection/) Cocoa framework, which is able to upload data to different services, including Amazon S3. I am pretty sure it has some starting points for you in its source.